# FOSRestBundle View annotation not working

Tags: php, rest, symfony-2.1, fosrestbundle

`config.yml:`

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: 
        default_priorities: [json, xml]
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'  

sensio_framework_extra:
    view:    { annotations: false }
    router:  { annotations: true }
```

`annotated controller:`

```
/**
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=204)
 * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
 */
public function signUpAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->get('%%%.response_generator')->generateResponse(array('test'), true, 'test'); 
    // returns a simple Object with some public properties
}
```

If I access the route with `.json` format it returns:

```
{"status":1,"message":"test","data":["test"]}
```

But it won't change the status code to the one from annotation.

Also without a specified format, it doesn't fallback to the default `.json` format, it still searches for a template.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
```

And then in the action:

```
$view = View::create($response, 204);
return $view;
```